# How do I copy and paste from the Basic D&D rules?

Tags: dnd-5e

As I've been answering questions on the stack, I've noticed that it's rather difficult to copy and paste text from the Basic D&D rules.

Here is what I get when I try to copy text from the PDF (in Chrome):

> Blinded
>   9Zdaf][j]Ylmj][YfÌlk]]Yf\YmlgeYla[Yddq^Yadk
>   YfqYZadalq['][cl'Ylj]imaj]kka_'l&
>   9llY[cjgddkY_Yafkll'][j]Ylmj]'Yn]Y\nYflY_]$Yf\
>   l'][j]Ylmj]ÌkYllY[cjgddk'Yn]\akY\nYflY_]&

And with the default Windows 8 PDF reader it's even worse, search doesn't even work, the first reference to blinded is the line above.

Obviously that's not useful. I'd much rather *not* have to copy things by hand, is there a better way?

Answer (score 26):

There is a much better way to do this. Later on July 3rd, Wizards released the printer friendly version of the Basic PDF. It is far more useful when it comes to copy and pasting text from the basic PDF into the browser or a word processor.

Here is a sample text from there:

> Blinded
>
> - A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight.
> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature’s attack rolls have disadvantage.

This printer friendly version of the basic rules is available [here](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/DnDBasicRules(PrinterFriendly).pdf).

Answer (score 4):

If you have adobe acrobat and open the pdf in the desktop application, you can highlight text and right click choosing 'copy with formatting' it will then copy the text properly.  Also search works great.